# Disable ubuntu's user password to contain 4 consecutive characters on the keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, passwords, pam

I'm currently setting up a password for my Ubuntu account, and I need to restrict consecutive characters on the keyboard to no longer than 4 characters. For example, strings like qwer and VCXZ.

So i added the below content to the /etc/security/pwquality.conf file.
badwords = qwer wert erty rtyu tyui yuio uiop asdf sdfg dfgh fghj ghjk hjkl zxcv xcvb cvbn vbnm 7890

but i think it's unclear way so i want to find better way